# Getting nullpointer exception with PrimeFaces autocomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

Having problems with autocomplete primefaces. When I select any one of the autocomplete tag, first time it works without any issue. But when I select it for second time it throws below error.

```
SEVERE: Error during partial-page rendering
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:491)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:393)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:580)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:762)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.PanelPartialRootRenderer$EncodeAllCallback.visit(PanelPartialRootRenderer.java:231)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.ppr.PartialPageContextImpl$PartialPageVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialPageContextImpl.java:398)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1073)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:952)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1073)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:952)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1073)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:952)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.visitTree(UIComponentBase.java:1073)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.visitChildrenForEncoding(CoreRenderer.java:228)
```

Below is the code

```
<tr:inputDate id="endDate" value="#{projectMgdBean.addProject.end_Date }" required="true" requiredMessageDetail="end Date Missing"/>
<tr:outputLabel value="Test Efforts:" for="efforts"/>
<tr:inputText id="efforts" value="#{projectMgdBean.addProject.efforts }" required="false" requiredMessageDetail="end Date Missing"/>
<p:outputLabel id="countryLabel" value="Tester: " />
<h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGrid>
<p:autoComplete id="tester1" vallue="#{projectMgdBean.addProject.tester1}" completeMethod="#{projectMgdBean.getEmails()}" cache="true"/>
<p:autoComplete id="tester2" vallue="#{projectMgdBean.addProject.tester2}" completeMethod="#{projectMgdBean.getEmails1()}"/>
<p:autoComplete id="tester3" vallue="#{projectMgdBean.addProject.tester3}" completeMethod="#{projectMgdBean.getEmails2()}" />
</h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

I am using JSF 1.2 and primeFaces 5.0

Comment: IIRC, PF 5 does not work on JSF 1.2...

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if null value is returned from complete method

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen if the autocomplete is within a *masterdetail* and its disabled attribute changes.